# Access the Coinbase Candles url

Tags: c#, rest-client, coinbase-api

I have successfully managed to call some of Coinbase API's end points, but struggling on calling the Candles Url:

```
        using RestSharp;
        using System.Globalization;
        using System.Net.Http;
        using System.Security.Cryptography;
        using System.Text;

        var symbol = "BTC-GBP";
        var _privateApiKey = "xxxx";
        var _secret = "xxxxxxxxxx";
        var _timestamp = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeSeconds().ToString();
        var _requestPath = "/api/v3/brokerage/products/" + symbol + "/candles";
        var _method = "GET";

        var client = new RestClient(@"https://api.coinbase.com" + _requestPath + "?granularity=ONE_DAY&start=" + DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(-3000).ToUniversalTime().Ticks + "&end=" + DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().Ticks + "");

        var request = new RestRequest();
        request.Method = Method.Get;
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        request.AddHeader("CB-ACCESS-KEY", _privateApiKey);
        request.AddHeader("CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP", _timestamp);
        request.AddHeader("CB-ACCESS-SIGN", GetAccessSign(_timestamp, _method, _requestPath, "", _secret));
        request.AddHeader("CB-VERSION", "2023-01-18");



        try
        {

            var response = client.Execute(request);
            Console.WriteLine(response.Content);


        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
        string GetAccessSign(string timestamp, string method, string path, string body, string apiSecret)
        {
            var convertedString = Convert.FromBase64String(apiSecret);
            var hmaccsha = new HMACSHA256(convertedString);

            string timestampStr = timestamp;
            string httpMethodStr = method;
            var prehash = timestampStr + httpMethodStr + path + body;

            // Convert the input string and key to byte arrays
            byte[] prehashBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(prehash);
            byte[] keyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(apiSecret);

            // Compute the SHA-256 hash of the input data using the key
            HMACSHA256 hmac = new HMACSHA256(keyBytes);
            byte[] hash2 = hmac.ComputeHash(prehashBytes);

            // Convert the hash to a hexadecimal string
            string signedSignature = BitConverter.ToString(hash2).Replace("-", "").ToLower();

            return signedSignature;
        }
```

But i keep getting this error:

```
{"error":"INVALID_ARGUMENT","error_details":"start and end argument is invalid - number of candles requested should be less than 300 ","message":"start and end argument is invalid - number of candles requested should be less than 300 "}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the required arguments:
https://docs.cloud.coinbase.com/advanced-trade-api/reference/retailbrokerageapi_getcandles

> Path Params
>
> product_id string required
> The trading pair.

> Query Params
>
> start string required
> Timestamp for starting range of aggregations, in UNIX time.
>
> end string required
> Timestamp for ending range of aggregations, in UNIX time.
>
> granularity string required
> The time slice value for each candle.

The API probably just has a bad error message and treats undefined start and end range query params as out of range values.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the results back using this in the RestClient and to Tomáš Hübelbauer link:

```
 var client = new RestClient(string.Format(@"https://api.coinbase.com" + _requestPath + "?granularity=ONE_MINUTE&start={0}&end={1}", DateTimeOffset.Now.AddSeconds(-6000).ToUnixTimeSeconds(), DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeSeconds()));
```

Which gave me about 30 to 35 elements of data back